# On Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu 22.04 don't work ioctl

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, kernel, driver, webcam

I have Raspberry Pi 4 (aarch64 Cortex-A72) with OS Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 64-bit installed. I try read frame from webcam.

When I run this code:

```
if (ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &buf) < 0) {
    std::cout << "V4lNode failed  dequeue frame from buffer: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
}
```

I get output result:

*V4lNode failed dequeue frame from buffer: Resource temporarily unavailable*

But device opened success:

```
fd = open(path.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK, 0);
std::cout << "V4lNode open files discription: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
```

Output result:

*V4lNode open files discription: Success*

When I run v4l2 tests in terminal:

```
pi@pi:~$ v4l2-compliance 
v4l2-compliance 1.22.1, 64 bits, 64-bit time_t

Compliance test for uvcvideo device /dev/video0:

Driver Info:
    Driver name      : uvcvideo
    Card type        : Intel F450
    Bus info         : usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1
    Driver version   : 5.15.39
    Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
        Video Capture
        Metadata Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps      : 0x04200001
        Video Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
Media Driver Info:
    Driver name      : uvcvideo
    Model            : Intel F450
    Serial           : 00.00.01
    Bus info         : usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1
    Media version    : 5.15.39
    Hardware revision: 0x00000100 (256)
    Driver version   : 5.15.39
Interface Info:
    ID               : 0x03000002
    Type             : V4L Video
Entity Info:
    ID               : 0x00000001 (1)
    Name             : Intel F450
    Function         : V4L2 I/O
    Flags            : default
    Pad 0x01000007   : 0: Sink
      Link 0x02000010: from remote pad 0x100000a of entity 'Extension 3' (Video Pixel Formatter): Data, Enabled, Immutable

Required ioctls:
    test MC information (see 'Media Driver Info' above): OK
    test VIDIOC_QUERYCAP: OK
    test invalid ioctls: OK

Allow for multiple opens:
    test second /dev/video0 open: OK
    test VIDIOC_QUERYCAP: OK
    test VIDIOC_G/S_PRIORITY: OK
    test for unlimited opens: OK

Debug ioctls:
    test VIDIOC_DBG_G/S_REGISTER: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_LOG_STATUS: OK (Not Supported)

Input ioctls:
    test VIDIOC_G/S_TUNER/ENUM_FREQ_BANDS: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_G/S_FREQUENCY: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_S_HW_FREQ_SEEK: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_ENUMAUDIO: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_G/S/ENUMINPUT: OK
    test VIDIOC_G/S_AUDIO: OK (Not Supported)
    Inputs: 1 Audio Inputs: 0 Tuners: 0

Output ioctls:
    test VIDIOC_G/S_MODULATOR: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_G/S_FREQUENCY: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_ENUMAUDOUT: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_G/S/ENUMOUTPUT: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_G/S_AUDOUT: OK (Not Supported)
    Outputs: 0 Audio Outputs: 0 Modulators: 0

Input/Output configuration ioctls:
    test VIDIOC_ENUM/G/S/QUERY_STD: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_ENUM/G/S/QUERY_DV_TIMINGS: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_DV_TIMINGS_CAP: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_G/S_EDID: OK (Not Supported)

Control ioctls (Input 0):
        fail: v4l2-test-controls.cpp(246): missing control class for class 00980000
    test VIDIOC_QUERY_EXT_CTRL/QUERYMENU: FAIL
    test VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL: OK
    test VIDIOC_G/S_CTRL: OK
        warn: v4l2-test-controls.cpp(757): g_ext_ctrls(0) invalid error_idx 0
    test VIDIOC_G/S/TRY_EXT_CTRLS: OK
    test VIDIOC_(UN)SUBSCRIBE_EVENT/DQEVENT: OK
    test VIDIOC_G/S_JPEGCOMP: OK (Not Supported)
    Standard Controls: 1 Private Controls: 0

Format ioctls (Input 0):
    test VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT/FRAMESIZES/FRAMEINTERVALS: OK
    test VIDIOC_G/S_PARM: OK
    test VIDIOC_G_FBUF: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_G_FMT: OK
    test VIDIOC_TRY_FMT: OK
        warn: v4l2-test-formats.cpp(1036): Could not set fmt2
    test VIDIOC_S_FMT: OK
    test VIDIOC_G_SLICED_VBI_CAP: OK (Not Supported)
    test Cropping: OK (Not Supported)
    test Composing: OK (Not Supported)
    test Scaling: OK (Not Supported)

Codec ioctls (Input 0):
    test VIDIOC_(TRY_)ENCODER_CMD: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_G_ENC_INDEX: OK (Not Supported)
    test VIDIOC_(TRY_)DECODER_CMD: OK (Not Supported)

Buffer ioctls (Input 0):
    test VIDIOC_REQBUFS/CREATE_BUFS/QUERYBUF: OK
    test VIDIOC_EXPBUF: OK
    test Requests: OK (Not Supported)

Total for uvcvideo device /dev/video0: 46, Succeeded: 45, Failed: 1, Warnings: 2
```

I get error:

```
Control ioctls (Input 0):
        fail: v4l2-test-controls.cpp(246): missing control class for class 00980000
    test VIDIOC_QUERY_EXT_CTRL/QUERYMENU: FAIL
```

Outputs formats:

```
pi@pi:~$ v4l2-ctl --list-formats
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Type: Video Capture

    [0]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
```

Output `dmesg` errors:

```
[    0.823576] zswap: compressor zstd not available, using default lzo
[    0.829609] zswap: zpool z3fold not available, using default zbud
[  102.238315] uvcvideo 1-1.1:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-1).
[  102.238626] uvcvideo 1-1.1:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-1).
[ 5822.239686] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[ 5822.249854] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[ 5822.259913] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[ 5822.269949] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[ 5822.280057] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[ 5822.290139] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[ 5822.391565] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 5822.401637] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 5822.411679] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 5822.421697] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 5822.431779] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 5822.441885] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 5822.532650] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[ 5822.563375] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 5822.622056] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[ 5823.168241] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[ 5823.270367] usb 1-1.1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
```

I am tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46253564/recording-usb-cam-on-raspberry-pi-with-ffmpeg-usb-troubleshooting - don't worked

Do you have an ideas?